# How to Highlight Date and Time field in Sharepoint list when it is 1 month further?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xcode, sharepoint

I working on SharePoint list and it has some important Dates so I need to highlight fields when [Today]= dueDate-30
Of course I have tried with java and I found this code but it doesn't work:
hope all is going well. Sine I am a fresh code maker if any one can help me I appreciate.

```
function CheckStatus() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD") // find all of the TDs
    var _dueDate = new Date();
    var now = new Date();
    var nowPlus30 = new Date();
    nowPlus30.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);

    var nowPlus90 = new Date();
    nowPlus90.setDate(now.getDate() + 90);

    if (_dueDate == '' || !_dueDate) {
        return '';
    }
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        if (x[i].className == "ms-vb2") //find the TDs styled for lists
        {

            if( _dueDate <= nowPlus30 ) //find the data to use to determine the color
            {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; // set the color
            }

            //repeat the above for each data value

            if (_dueDate <= nowPlus90) {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // set the color
            }

            if (_dueDate > nowPlus30) {
                x[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // set the color
            }


        }

    }
}​
```